# Timestamps taken by rosbag play (and rqt_bag) and by rosbag.Bag's read_messages() differ

Tags: ros, rosbag

There is something very strange happening with some rosbags I have.
These rosbags contain messages of type `sensor_msgs/Image` among other topics.

So I do:

**First scenario**

On one terminal I run `rostopic echo /the_image/header` because I am not interested in the actual data, just the header info.
In another terminal I run `rosbag play --clock the_bag.bag`

With this I get

```
seq: 7814
stamp: 
  secs: 1625151029
  nsecs: 882629359
frame_id: ''
---
seq: 7815
stamp: 
  secs: 1625151029
  nsecs: 934761166
frame_id: ''
---
seq: 7816
stamp: 
  secs: 1625151029
  nsecs: 986241550
frame_id: ''
---
seq: 7817
stamp: 
  secs: 1625151030
  nsecs:  82884301
frame_id: ''
---
```

**Second Scenario**
I do the same as the previous scenario but instead of rosbag play I run `rqt_bag the_bag.bag` and once there I right click the message to *publish* them.
With that I get similar values but (I have reported the problem before) the first messages are skipped. (this is not the problem of this question)

**Third Scenario**

Here comes the weird part. Instead of doing as above I have a python script that does

```
timestamps=[]
for topic, msg, t in  rosbag.Bag("the_bag.bag").read_messages():
    if topic == '/the_image':
        timestamps.append((image_idx, t))
with open("timestamps.txt",'w') as f:
    for idx, t in timestamps:
        f.write('{0},{1},{2}\n'.format(str(idx).zfill(8), t.secs, t.nsecs))
```

So as you can see I open the bag and get a list of timestamps and record it in a text file.
Which gives:

```
00000000,1625151029,987577614
00000001,1625151030,33818541
00000002,1625151030,88932237
00000003,1625151030,170311084
00000004,1625151030,232427083
00000005,1625151030,279726253
00000006,1625151030,363255375
00000007,1625151030,463079346
00000008,1625151030,501315763
00000009,1625151030,566104245
00000010,1625151030,586694806
```

As you can see the values **are totally different!!!**

What could be happening here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known "issue" with `rostopic echo` and bag files. I put issue in quotes because it's not necessarily an issue, but just a product of how `rostopic` works. To spare the somewhat obscure details of the implementation, this problem essentially happens because `rospy.rostime` does not get initialized correctly when just playing a bag file and echoing that; even if you set `/use_sim_time` to true.

To give some clarity on what you're seeing, the timestamps coming off your Python script are correct and the rostopic ones are not. If you need the timestamps to be 100% correct with rostopic you can use the `-b` flag like: `rostoic echo -b the_bag.bag /my_image_topic`